# Wait 5 seconds (instead of click) before runIt?

Tags: jquery, wait

currently a click initates the sequence in my code. I'd like to change it so that "Start Again" fades in, appears for 5 seconds, then fades out and the rest of the sequence runs.

Complete beginner! I'm not sure how to do that. Any help?

```
$(document).ready(runIt);

});


function runIt(){
$('#myText').hover(function(){
        $(this).clearQueue().html('Start Again');
})
  .click(function(){
    runIt();
  })
  .html('text 1')
  .fadeIn(1000)
  .delay(5000)
  .fadeOut(1000,function(){
    $(this).html('text 2');
  })
  .fadeIn(1000)
  .delay(5000)
  .fadeOut(1000,function(){
    $(this).html('text 3').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
  })
  .fadeIn(1000);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $(window).mousemove(function(){
    runIt();
  });
  runIt();      
})

function runIt() {
  var it = $('#myText');
  it.stop(true,true).clearQueue().fadeOut(1).animate({left:0},500).queue(function(){
    it.html('Start Again');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(500).animate({left:0},5000).fadeOut(1000).queue(function(){
    it.html('test 1');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(1000).animate({left:0},5000).fadeOut(1000).queue(function(){
    it.html('test 2');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(1000).animate({left:0},5000).fadeOut(1000).queue(function(){
    it.html('test 3');
    $(window).unbind('mousemove');
    it.dequeue();
  })
  it.fadeIn(1000);
}
```

The delay function does not get cleared properly so I used a static animation to fake a delay (animate left in this case).

Comment: hi there, thanks for this! I am testing it, but haven't managed to get it to work for some reason... In terms of what I want to happen: I want there to be a sequence of texts that automatically fading in and out on the screen but if the user moves the mouse I want the sequence to be interupted with "start again". If they make it to the last text, I want that to remain on the screen and not be affected by mouse movement.

Comment: When you say moves the mouse do you mean anywhere on the screen or just over the element in which the animated text resides? Also when you say interrupted with "start again" do you mean the animation gets reset

Comment: @TheBendArrow yes anywhere on the screen and also any keystrokes if possible. Yes the animation gets reset. Basically I want something like on this site: donothingfor2minutes.com .. except that instead of a timer there are some messages fading in and out.

Comment: I just updated the code to reflect the information you just provided. Give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks thats really fantastic! It works great! Would it be possible to somehow have another div that fades in with the 'test 1' text but rather than fading out with it, stays on screen and then fades out with 'test 2'?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a couple of functions that you can use for this: setTimeout() and setInterval(). Here's a good post on them: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

So in your case, instead of calling runit() based on a click you will need to call it from setTimeout() or setInterval():

```
setTimeout('runit()', 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested but this is closer to what you want... note that runIt() has been moved to an external function.

```
$(function () {
  $('#myText').hover(function(){
      $(this).clearQueue().html('Start Again');
    }).click(function(){  runIt();  });
  });


function runIt() {
  $(this)
    .html('text 1')
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(1000,function(){
      $(this).html('text 2');
    })
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .delay(5000)
    .fadeOut(1000,function(){
      $(this).html('text 3').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    })
    .fadeIn(1000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).ready(function()
{
    setTimeout("runIt();", 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully tested and working code with a few changes, you can make changes to it to what ever you'd like.

hope this helps.

edit: if you wish to stop events you should use .stop() and not .clearQueue()

```
    (function($) {

    jQuery.fn.idle = function(time) {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: '+=0'
        }, time);
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);



$(document).ready(function() {
    runIt();
    function runIt() {
    $('#myText').idle(5000).text('Start Again').fadeOut(5000, function() {
        $(this).text('text 1');
        $(this).fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(5000, function() {
                $(this).text('text 2');
                $(this).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    $(this).fadeOut(5000, function() {
                        $(this).text('text 3');
                        $(this).fadeIn(1000, function() {
                            $(this).fadeOut(5000, function() {
                                //runIt();
                                //uncomment the above if you want a loop.
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
    };
});
```